# Tree: 树 (shù) vs 木 (mù)

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context

Is there any difference between 树 (shù) and 木 (mù), in the meaning of "tree", or they are interchangeable?

Comment: 树 means 'tree', while 木 can mean both 'tree' and 'wood(en)'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

树 more often means tree in modern language, while 木 usually means wood, as in 木板 (plank) or 木材 (timber).

An olive tree is 橄榄树, while a birch is 桦木. Most trees are 树, though.

Comment: dict。cn：桦树有光滑的皮和细长的枝。
The birch has smooth bark and slender branches.
乔木 tree （落叶乔木deciduous tree）  灌木 bush ； shrub，however evergreen tree：常青树

Comment: What about a "generic" tree, like in: "Look at that tree over there!"? Which chinese word should be used?

Comment: 树：那棵树很漂亮。Plural: 树木, trees. Forest: 树林. As for biology, 木 is genus or family (as in 桦木), while 树 usually is species (桦树).

Answer (score 2):

树 = tree, 木 = wood or wooden.
Pretty much the same usage as in English